# Node js mysql query result ,can i get just the date without the name?

Tags: mysql, node.js

**I HAVE THIS CODE**

```
    app.post('/check',urlencodedParser,function (req, res) {
  let sql=`SELECT dbdateentre  FROM reservation WHERE idchambre = ${req.body.room}`;
  let query=db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
    
      console.log(result);

  })
});
```

and this is the result in console.log
it returns me this
`[ RowDataPacket { dbdateentre: 2020-12-17T23:00:00.000Z } ]`

Comment: Could you copy-paste your code here? With the log output

Comment: app.post('/check',urlencodedParser,function (req, res) {
  //pour creer une format de date
  dateFormat.masks.hammerTime = 'd';
  var dateentree=req.body.dateentry;
  var format=dateFormat(dateentree, "hammerTime");
  let sql=`SELECT dbdateentre  FROM reservation WHERE idchambre = ${req.body.room}`;
  let query=db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{


      console.log(result);

  })
});

app.listen('3000',()=>{
  console.log('server started an Port 3000')
});

Comment: Nice. Could you edit your post and insert it there?

Comment: i am new in stackoverflow ,i try

Comment: if you click on "i have this code" you can get it

Comment: Hi, this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: done i pasted thoe code ,it's a simple query but the result  is different and i want just the date from the database

Comment: thank you @HanielBaez , please can you solve me this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sure that your returns would be only one row you can try this code

```
console.log(result[0].dbdateentre)
```

Comment: thannnnnk youuuuuuuuu so mucccch it worked!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: now i have a lot of rows how can i return them all ?